# Cannot Suspend vi with Ctrl-Z

Tags: unix, vi, aix

It's on an AIX 6.1 connected via PuTTY 0.65.

If I open a file and hit Ctrl-Z then. It works 1st. But when I switch back and hit Ctrl-Z again. A square cursor jumps to the bottom. I can type something but it can't be escaped to vi's command mode.

It's frustrating and I have to open up another session to kill the vi.

```
chingnotching@abcdev:/home/chingnotching/tmp> vi testFile
"testFile" 28 lines, 75 characters
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
"testFile" 28 lines, 75 characters
[1] +                          vi testFile
chingnotching@abcdev:/home/chingnotching/tmp> fg
vi testFile
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23

_
```

Comment: You want to go to command mode? `Ctrl C` or `ESC` will help, won't they?

Comment: Tried. No, they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Type ps command
it will show something like this

```
ps
PID    TTY  TIME CMD
598070  pts/6  0:00 -ksh
671970  pts/6  0:00 vi struct.c
680160  pts/6  0:00 ps
```

u can kill the process then try..
i hope it will solve your problem